# How do Green Lanterns breathe in space?

Tags: comics, dc, green-lantern

I understand it is a power of the ring but I was curious if they ever explain how it works. It seems to be some protective aura that does it as they are never seen in space without that but it prevent them from needing air, or do they generate construct air to use for breathing?

Comment: Nothing can generate matter that is Newtons law, though the aura could break the CO2 chain refreshing the air suply; granted this is spculation

Comment: The green lantern rings are literally magical, unless this has been reconned away. The Guardians gathered up "all the random magic in the universe" and used it to make the battery. Presumably it does not need to obey the laws of physics.

Comment: As a guess, just to get past "omg it's physics breaking," those rings have enough power to protect and fly a squishy creature across the galaxy so I'm going to go ahead and say that they have enough power to both harvest interstellar matter and retcon it into usable molecules in addition to acting as a rebreather.

Comment: @PatrickHughes I would guess there is something like that too, I was just wondering if my guess is correct. It may just be "it's magic" but I find often with things like this I find it is explained somewhere. Especially in a universe where there is both magic and advanced science.

Comment: The other possibility is that the rings negate the need for a breathable environment, but the wearer still thinks they are breathing. (I know it's been stated in the comics that the aura provides an environment similar to the wearer's home, but I'm throwing out a much easier way to get around the matter transmutation issue)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### It is never clearly established how the [Power Ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_ring_%28DC_Comics%29) creates a hospitable life-support environment for its ring bearer. No matter the biome of the user, the ring creates and maintains life support for the wielder in any environment.

- Unless otherwise specified, the protective aura is personal and skin-tight. The wielder of the ring does not need to do anything for the protection from inhospitable environments. As long as the ring is charged, it will automatically provide life support as needed.
- If there is no air, the ring provides it, possibly by transmuting matter from the environment, possibly by simply creating what it needs from within the wielder or from the environment (stray molecular matter converted during space travel into oxygen, and/or converting exhaled gases back into oxygen). Transmutation of matter is child's play for the ring.
- The Green Lantern rings are NOT magical. The Guardians DID gather up all the magical energy in the Universe and cast that magical object into space. It gained sentience and became the [Starheart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_ring_%28DC_Comics%29#Starheart). It also landed on Earth and was converted into a Green Lantern and attendant ring. This was the ring used by the first Green Lantern during the Golden Age, [Alan Scott](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Scott).

Answer (score 0):

The power rings are an advanced technology developed by the guardians to serve as a tool to aid their bearers. As such, they are extremely powerful and versatile devices that must be recharged with battery lanterns. Seeing as matter is just solid energy, it makes sense that the energy stored would then be converted to a breathable oxygen mixture if needed. This means that the amount of oxygen-mixture that the ring can make is finite. I wish that I had some numbers for you, but I don't. This mixture would then be made available in the form-fit bubble around them that resists the vacuum of space.